# Ansible. Trying to get the 3rd octet of an IP address from a string to use as a variable

Tags: ansible

Been trying to get the 3rd octet of an IP address by taking the output and putting it into a variable and then splitting it.  Not sure if there's a better way of doing it but here's how I've tried and hasn't worked.

```
---
- name: Gather Information'
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - show run int g0/1.220 | in ip add
  register: output

- msg: 
  var="{{ output.stdout.split(" ")[3] }}""

the output looks like "IP address 10.10.80.1 255.255.255.224".
```

I'm trying to divide that to get the IP and then divide it again to get the 3rd octet. "80" to use as a variable somewhere else.

jmyths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
{{output.stdout.split(" ")[2].split(".")[2]}}
```

You were almost there anyway.

--EDIT-- Oops. Wrong language.

```
{{ output.stdout | regex_replace("^[^0-9]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+ .*$", "\\1") }}
```

That should apply the regex_replace filter to output.stdout, using a match string of "start then not numbers followed by nums.nums.(match 1).nums anything", and replace it with match group 1.

https://www.tailored.cloud/devops/how-to-filter-and-map-lists-in-ansible/

Sorry. I mistook the scripting language you were using, and did a quick double-take when I saw the tag.

Comment: Hi Sam, Tried adding just the last bit... ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  could not find expected ':'

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/roles/info_gathering/tasks/main.yml': line 10, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Can you try that updated filter, @jmyths? I was mistaken about the language you were using.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Regex string did the trick. Now to try and expand it to the next part of the script.